# How can I upload my python script to the web/Facebook without completely rewriting my code?

Tags: python, facebook, python-2.7, web

I'm creating a Text Based Adventure in Python that runs in Terminal, but before I progress I would like to know if it's possible to upload it to the web or create a Facebook app with it without rewriting everything. I've searched the web for hours trying to find something that allows me to do this. I found something called IronPython but couldn't figure out how to use it in the way I would want.

My code contains things such as:

```
def pillar_start2():    
    print "North end of a pillared corridor."
    print "There is a passage to the East and West."
    print "Upon closer inspection you notice some Hieroglyphs."
    itemcheck(ipillar_start)
    print
    prompt_start()

def prompt_start():
        global gold
        prompt_h = raw_input("Type a command: ").lower()
        try:
            global northroom
            global eastroom
            global westroom
            global southroom
            if prompt_h in northroom:
        print "There is no room to the North."
        print
        prompt_start()
    elif prompt_h in eastroom:
        empty_room()
```

So to be specific my question is: How can I use code such as the above as a facebook app while rewriting a minimum of my code.

Cheers, Jacob (I've had an idea of running my python script in another programming language but have had no luck with that so far. This perhaps may be because I know nothing other than Python and Unix.)

Comment: **Short Answer** you can't. Web applications can't be written in Python, it has to be written in JS.

Comment: You can host it on Google App Engine or Heroku, but you'd need to do some server-side coding (Flask, e.g.) and also some client-side coding, with HTML and JavaScript.

Comment: Sure web applications can be written in python. You are going to have to find some way of turning your text based adventure game into one.  But as to where to start, geez.  You might try looking at the flask documentation: http://flask.pocoo.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way I can imagine is that you create a console online

https://www.python.org/ click "Launch Interactive Shell"

read a blog post about it http://blog.pythonanywhere.com/83/

[image: Interactive console - sharable]
Main program is restartable: (Idea)

```
while 1:
    try:
        # main program

    except KeyboardInterrupt: 
        pass # restart the program when STRG-C is pressed
```

Or you could use https://trinket.io/ or pythonfiddle

Comment: Awesome, I've got an online console with my script running fine using Ipython. But is there any way of booting into my script on start-up? If I was running terminal normally I could boot into my file by typing "Ipython my_file.py". And if not, what bad things could people do? (I also presume I need to pay to upload this to facebook or any other domain)

Comment: I do not know how you can boot into the script. This may be impossible. You should ask the developers from pythonanywhere. But you can create a free account and share your console there. I think this is possible. But then all users would use the same program.

Comment: Anyone know how I could have a individual console per person? As currently when someone access's it, it continues where the last person left off.

Comment: I think you need to create a console for each person.. But maybe you can rewrite your program. I added somethig to restart with STRG-C

Answer (score 3):

On PythonAnywhere, we have a (slightly hidden) feature called "gist consoles".  If you take your script and save it as a gist on github, then you can share it with anyone on the internet via a console that will automatically load that gist:

https://www.pythonanywhere.com/gists/

here's an example:

https://www.pythonanywhere.com/gists/5502596/robot.py/ipython3/warning

So you could actually edit your code via the gist on github, and whenever you want to view your changes, you can hit save on github, then hit refresh on the pythonanywhere gist console link, and see an updated version...